# For loop doesn't add correct amount of values to array

Tags: php

My for loop should be adding 9 values to an array, but for some reason stops on 6. This only happens when I use the square bracket syntax to add the key and value to the array. Here's the code:

```
       $sentences = $this->sentences($sentence);
    $n = count($sentences);
    echo $n;
    $values = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
        $s1 = $sentences[$i];
        for($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++){
            $s2 = $sentences[$j];
            $values[$i][$j] = $this->checkvalues($s1,$s2);
        }
    }
    $sentences_dic = array();
    $other = array();
    $otherTwo = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
        $score = 0;
        for($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++){
            $score = $score+$values[$i][$j];

        }
        $other[$i] = $score;
        $otherTwo[$i] = $sentences[$i];
        $sentences_dic[($sentences[$i])]=$score;
        var_dump($otherTwo);
    }
    //maybe need
    return $sentences_dic;
```

I am not sure why this is happening. The array is only printing
Here is what it is printing. It should be printing the seventh, eigth and ninth terms but it isnt. All the terms it isn't adding were all able to print in the other and otherTwo arrays.

```
Array
(
[first] => banana
[second] => banana2
[third] => banana3
[fourth] => banana4
[fifth] => banana5
[sixth] => banana6
)
```

when it should be printing all 9 values and keys. I don't understand why I am able to add all sentences and scores to their full extent(9) to two seperate arrays, but when I try to use square bracket syntax it only goes to 6.

Comment: We don't see where or how you declare `$values`, `$other`, `$otherTwo`, `$sentences` nor `$sentences_dic`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `$sentences` has duplicates.

Comment: Oh, nicely spotted @AbraCadaver! I tip my hat. Something else (unrelated): `$sentences_dic[($sentences[$i])]` can be simplified to `$sentences_dic[$sentences[$i]]` (without the regular brackets).

Comment: Sorry @domdom  I edited in the complete code.

Comment: and $sentence is what is passed by the function. It's just a piece of text.

Comment: `$sentences` appears to be an array and has duplicates.  `print_r($sentences);`

Comment: oh. @AbraCadaver  thank you. You are right. There are duplicated. Thank you.

Comment: @AbraCadaver maybe write it up as a short answer then so we can get this question out of the queue. :)

Comment: Was a short answer so I elaborated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your output `$sentences` appears to be an array and has duplicates. Array keys must be unique and duplicate keys are overwritten.

You could do something like this for a multidimensional array:

```
if(isset($sentences_dic[$sentences[$i]])) {
     $sentences_dic[$sentences[$i]][] = $score;
} else {
     $sentences_dic[$sentences[$i]] = $score;
}
```

Or to sum the scores of duplicates:

```
if(isset($sentences_dic[$sentences[$i]])) {
     $sentences_dic[$sentences[$i]] += $score;
} else {
     $sentences_dic[$sentences[$i]] = $score;
}
```